# How to fetch multiple API and load data individually in the following example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch multiple API in react. The first API successfully fetch and display results but the second and third of the same API gave error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined".

I am sure the API works correctly because it is the same API call as the first API.

```
if(str1 != ""){
fetch('http://someapi/' + str1)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => this.setState({ result1: data }))
}
if(str2 != ""){
fetch('http://someapi/' + str2)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => this.setState({ result1: data }))
}
if(str3 != ""{
fetch('http://someapi/' + str3)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => this.setState({ result1: data }))
}
```

Expected output for all 3 results

> [{name: a, age: 1}, {name: b, age: 3}]

However, the very first fetch is successful with correct response store into the state. The rest of the API call did not finish its fetching.

Any idea why this is happening? And code to remedy this issue?

Comment: in developer tools go to network tab and look what response you are getting from each api call, it one of them giving some error. Also what is point of making 3 different api calls when you are going to overwrite value received from two of them

Comment: Please share code in codesandbox

Comment: my bad. It is possible to run fetch simultaneously and return response individually to render into the component whichever api return response first. I have a spelling mistake hence, wasn't working. Now it's fix. Thank you!

Comment: Please add more context
 - str1,2 and 3 - what are they, are they user input or come as props or anything else?
 - do you need to call every time the all 3?